# Xamarin.Forms/UI: how align vertically an in item just between 2 layouts

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms, vertical-alignment

I work on a Xamarin.Forms app that uses:

- a header containing a background color and some items (avatar, text)
- a footer containing a bakcground image and some buttons
- between the 2 headers, I would like to show another button, that is well aligned between the 2 containers

The expected result is something like this prototype:
[image]

I'm able to achieve this approximately, but not perfectly: this works fine on iPhone 6, but not exactly on an iPhone X.

The XAML code looks like that:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <Image Source="background.png" 
           Opacity="0.25" Aspect="AspectFill"                  
           RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
               "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
               "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>

    <Grid x:Name="Header"
          BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BlueColor}"
          RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
              "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
              "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.55, Constant=0}">

        <StackLayout ... />
    </Grid>

    <Grid RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
              "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=Header, Property=Height, Factor=0.90}"
          RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
              "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
          RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
              "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.45, Constant=0}}">


        <StackLayout Spacing="5" Padding="25,10,25,10"
                     VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                     RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                        "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">

            <Button Style="{DynamicResource CustomButton}" 
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource OrangeColor}" 
                    VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    Margin="30,0,30,0"/>

            //...
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The main container is a `RelativeLayout`. The I set the `Image` as background 
 image of this layout. I have then a `StackLayout` as Header that contains the avatar and the user's details, and a second `StackLayout` that contains the Buttons.

***Is this a good approach? Or is there a better way to put the orange button between the 2 layouts?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as layout tips for Xamarin.Forms, there are some good ones here -> [Jason Smith's Xamarin Forms Performance Tips](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips).

It's difficult to fully understand your layout requirements without seeing all the code, but you may be able to simply use a `Grid` with 2 rows as the root/outer container.  The top content goes in the first row, the bottom content goes in the second row, and the button in between spans both rows and is vertically centered:

```xaml
<Grid RowSpacing="0">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition /> <!-- can adjust height based on needs -->
        <RowDefinition /> <!-- can adjust height based on needs -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- background image -->
    <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
           BackgroundColor="#EFEFEF" />

    <Grid x:Name="topContent" Grid.Row="0" 
          BackgroundColor="#20d1e0">
        <!-- top content here -->
    </Grid>

    <!-- middle button -->
    <Button x:Name="orangeButton" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
            BackgroundColor="#fda601" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="History"
            TextColor="White"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />

    <Grid x:Name="bottomContent" Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- bottom content here -->
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

[image]

---

**Update for uneven rows**

```xaml
<Grid RowSpacing="0">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.6*" /> <!-- can adjust height based on needs -->
        <RowDefinition Height="30" /> <!-- half the size of the orange button -->
        <RowDefinition Height="30" /> <!-- half the size of the orange button -->
        <RowDefinition Height="0.4*" /> <!-- can adjust height based on needs -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- background image -->
    <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
           BackgroundColor="#EFEFEF" />

    <Grid x:Name="topContent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
          BackgroundColor="#20d1e0">
        <!-- top content here -->
    </Grid>

    <!-- middle button -->
    <Button x:Name="orangeButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
            BackgroundColor="#fda601" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="History"
            TextColor="White"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />

    <Grid x:Name="bottomContent" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <!-- bottom content here -->
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @gannaway, your solution works well if the rows have the same height, but it's not my case (it's something like 60% / 40%). So how could I adapt your solution to this case?

Comment: Just set the row definitions to meet your needs.  For percentage based, `<RowDefinition Height="0.6*" /> <RowDefinition Height="0.4*" /> `.  You could also do something like this  `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <RowDefinition  /> `, where the first row would autosize, and the second row's height would fill the remaining screen space.

Comment: Yes I've did this, but in this case the OrangeButton is not "aligned" between the 2 rows.

Comment: Ah, I see, let me try something